# I tried to assign function to a variable and it broke

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to create a a shape and background that change color randomly. So far, I've been able to get a random color for both the circle and the body, but they need to be the same color. I've tried assigning the randomHsla function to a variable, randColor, but something is causing both the circle and the body's background color to turn white. How can I fix this?

```
var myCircle = document.querySelector("#circle");
        myCircle.style.backgroundColor = randomHsla();

var myBody = document.querySelector("body");
        myBody.style.backgroundColor = randomHsla(); 

function randomHsla() {
        return "hsla(" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 361) + ", 50%, 40%, 1)");
        }
```

Comment: so #circle and body need the same random colour?

Comment: Put the first four lines in a method and call that method using the result of randomHsla as argument is a way to use the same hsla code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var myCircle = document.querySelector("#circle");
var myBody = document.querySelector("body");
myCircle.style.backgroundColor = myBody.style.backgroundColor = randomHsla();
```

This way `randomHsla` is called exactly once, not twice

Comment: This way both body and circle background color will be same.

Comment: that's exactly right @Chayan - `they need to be the same color.` is a phrase used in the question